# On Markdown editing help page, example under Monospace Spans reads: "`https://`If your browser's location bar starts with ,"

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, editing-help

I picked this up on Law SE but it seems to be SE-wide:

There seems to be something missing between *with* and the *comma* in the address text written under the two entries for Monospace Spans:

> If your browser's location bar starts with [***What goes here?***] , then the connection is encrypted.

https://law.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

[image: Markdown help with the code formatting section quoted]

[image: code formatting help on Law SE]

(I can't work out how to do freehand drawing on my phone, sorry)

Comment: This was already reported here, but it seems that this part was missed: [Markdown help page is broken (badly presented/formatted) on every site](/q/347211/289905). The quote should be ``If your browser's location bar starts with `https://`, then the connection is encrypted.``, with both `\`` highlighted in dark gray.

Comment: @SebastianSimon: It seems like there's no dark gray highlighting at all in the "Preformatted text" section of the Markdown Editing Help page, unlike the other sections.

Comment: (Note: The Stack Overflow site's editing help page seems to have a different ["Code and Preformatted Text"](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) section at the start of the page, with different text; it doesn't have this issue. The editing help pages on the rest of the network do have the problem described above, however.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed. Along with a bunch of additional style regression issues that have crept into this component (formatting tips for sites that don't allow code styling). Over time a few things broke here - now the extra highlights on special characters and non-breaking spaces are back.

> code formatting tips
> text position and highlight
> errors reverted